# Cross-account, cross-region SQS / SNS subscription using Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have the following setup on AWS:

**Account A** owns an SNS topic in us-west-2. Permissions for subscription are allowed for anyone. I do not have access to an IAM role in this account.

**Account B** owns an SQS queue in eu-west-1. I have full access to this account.

I want to subscribe the SQS queue on account B to the topic on account A. I have tried the following with the AWS Java SDK, version 1.11:

```
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(<credentials from B>);
    snsClient.setEndpoint(<sns endpoint with region>);
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(region)));

    SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest()
            .withEndpoint(sqsQueueArn)
            .withProtocol("sqs")
            .withTopicArn(snsTopicArn);

    snsClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);
```

But I keep getting an `InvalidParameterException`:

```
com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 00e878c5-8766-5fe1-8670-281bd3ca8d87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1586)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1254)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:747)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:672)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:654)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:518)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2003)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:1979)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.subscribe(AmazonSNSClient.java:1881)
```

My theory of why this is happenning is that since the `snsClient` belongs to account B it is unable to find the SNS topic within the account, so it fails.

The question is, can I subscribe the SQS queue on B to the topic on A using the latest Java SDK for AWS?

Some more thoughts:

- It seems doable for Lambda functions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html , but for some reason it's not working in my case.
- I am able to do this subscription from Account B's UI, but not programmatically. So it might be a gap in the SDK itself.

Comment: Are both the topic and queue in the same region? You aren't trying to use a FIFO queue are you?

Comment: Not in the same region, not a FIFO queue. What bugs me is that it is possible from the UI, but it's failing with the SDK.

Comment: Are you sure you have the ARN format correct? Have you looked at the example of using the CLI for this here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cross.account.html

Comment: Got the solution: I need to specify the SNS topic's region, not the SQS queue's region. Realized that by trying it from the CLI, so thanks for the suggestion @MarkB !

Comment: Glad you figured it out.